# How to sum json objects based on the keys?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Given a column with json objects, how to sum them based on the keys using sql?

```
Table 3
-------
id, values
1, {"A": 10, "B": -5}
2, {"A": 20}
3, {"A": -15, "B": -5}
4, {"A": -10, "C": 77}
```

Also, regrouping the sum by another table relationship

```
Table1 has many Table3.
Table1 <-------- Table2 --------> Table 3

Table 1
-------
id
1
2 

Table 2
-------
id, table1_key, table3_key
1, 2, 3
2, 1, 4
```

Result:

```
Table 1 sums:
1, {"A": 5, "B": -5} # only sum of Table 3 id=2 and id=3
2, {"A": 0, "B": -5, "C": 77} # only sum of Table 3 id=1 and id=4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can first perform the summation via aggregation and then combine the results into a single JSON object with `jsonb_object_agg`:

```
select t4.id, jsonb_object_agg(t4.key, t4.val) from (
    select t2.id, v.key, sum(v.value::int) val from table2 t2 
    join table3 t3 on t3.id in (t2.table1_key, t2.table3_key)
    cross join jsonb_each(t3.js) v
    group by t2.id, v.key) t4
group by t4.id
order by t4.id
```

[See fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/q1ECHuz3)

Comment: Thank you. this works but I am struggling to add it to my context where my goal is to sum based on other tables' relationships. I updated the question to show these relationships, any chance you could help me figure out how to regroup before summing? Thank you.

Comment: @Michael Please see my recent edit.

Comment: Thank you, that helped. I was missing the group by at the 2 levels.

Answer (score 2):

Use `jsonb_each_text()` and the necessary casts for this:

```
with indata (j) as (
  values 
  ('{"A": 10, "B": -5}'::jsonb), ('{"A": 20}'),
  ('{"A": -15, "B": -5}'), ('{"A": -10, "C": 77}')
)
select k, sum(v::int)
  from indata
       cross join lateral jsonb_each_text(j) as e(k,v)
 group by k;
```

Working [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/sdhupe_w)

Comment: I see. Thanks. Can the output be built back into a json object? Maybe with `json_build_object` but not sure where to use it?

Comment: @Michael  Use `jsonb_object_agg()` on the result.